# What´s the right way to do deep notMatching() association in CakePHP 3

Tags: mysql, cakephp, orm, associations, cakephp-3.x

I'm trying to get the games that have no related records in the UsersTitles table when the user´s id is 2 (or another number), but I get all the games.

**Controller:**

```
$this->loadModel('Games');

$games = $this->Games->find()->notMatching('Titles.TitlesUsers', function ($q){
  return $q->where(['TitlesUsers.user_id'=> 2]);
})->distinct(['Games.id']);
```

**Games Table**

```
class GamesTable {    
  $this->hasMany('Titles', [
      'foreignKey' => 'game_id',
      'dependent' => true
  ]);
}
```

**Titles Table**

```
class TitlesTable {      
  $this->belongsTo('Games', ['dependent' => false]);

  $this->hasMany('TitlesUsers', [
    'classname' => 'TitlesUsers',
    'foreignKey' => 'title_id',
    'dependent' => true
  ]);    
}
```

**TitlesUsers Table**

```
class TitlesUsersTable {

  $this->belongsTo('Titles',['dependent'=>false]);

  $this->belongsTo('Users',['dependent'=>false]);

}
```

**Games table content**

```
id | name
---|---------
 1 | "Test A"
 2 | "Test B"
 3 | "Test C"
```

**Titles table content**

```
id | game_id
---|---------
 1 |       1
 2 |       1
 3 |       1
 4 |       2
 5 |       2
 6 |       2
 7 |       3
 8 |       3
 9 |       3
```

**TitlesUsers table content**

```
id | title_id | user_id
---|----------|---------
 1 |        1 |       2
```

**Generated SQL**

```
SELECT 
  Games.id AS `Games__id`, 
  Games.name AS `Games__name`
FROM 
  games Games 
  LEFT JOIN titles Titles ON Games.id = (Titles.game_id) 
  LEFT JOIN titles_users TitlesUsers ON (
    TitlesUsers.user_id = 2 
    AND Titles.id = (TitlesUsers.title_id)
  ) 
WHERE 
  (TitlesUsers.id) IS NULL 
GROUP BY 
  Games.id
```

If I do a notMatching() with a directly related table it works propertly. The problem appears when I´m trying to get deep level notMatching() association.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the expected result, in your setup there are 3 titles per game group, and only one of the titles has a user assigned, meaning for all other titles the user will be `NULL`, eg there are 2 titles for `Test A` left for which `(TitlesUsers.id) IS NULL` will be true.

Your non-grouped results would look like this:

```
| Games.id | Games.name | Titles.id | Titles.game_id | TitlesUsers.id | TitlesUsers.title_id | TitlesUsers.user_id |
| -------- | ---------- | --------- | -------------- | -------------- | -------------------- | ------------------- |
| 1        | Test A     | 1         | 1              | 1              | 1                    | 2                   |
| 1        | Test A     | 2         | 1              | NULL           | NULL                 | NULL                |
| 1        | Test A     | 3         | 1              | NULL           | NULL                 | NULL                |
| 2        | Test B     | 4         | 2              | NULL           | NULL                 | NULL                |
| 2        | Test B     | 5         | 2              | NULL           | NULL                 | NULL                |
| 2        | Test B     | 6         | 2              | NULL           | NULL                 | NULL                |
| 3        | Test C     | 7         | 3              | NULL           | NULL                 | NULL                |
| 3        | Test C     | 8         | 3              | NULL           | NULL                 | NULL                |
| 3        | Test C     | 9         | 3              | NULL           | NULL                 | NULL                |
```

As can be seen, every game group has at least one row where `TitlesUsers.id` is `NULL`.

You either need to rethink your database schema and associations, or if you need your schema to be that way, change how you filter things, as `notMatching()` isn't suited for it, for example exclude the games that you do not want by testing against the games for which at least one title from a specific user exists:

```php
$excludedGamesQuery = $this->Games
    ->find()
    ->select(['Games.id']);
    ->matching('Titles.TitlesUsers', function ($q){
        return $q->where(['TitlesUsers.user_id' => 2]);
    })
    ->group(['Games.id']);

$gamesQuery = $this->Games
    ->find()
    ->where([
        'Games.id NOT IN' => $excludedGamesQuery
    ]);
```